# How does one return a random number from a dictionary every time a key is called?

Tags: python, dictionary, random, properties, python-descriptors

I am trying to create a weapon that provides random damage. I am doing so using an item database in the form

```
itemsList = {
1: {"name": "Padded Armor",  "armor": 1,  "value": 5, "class": "Light"},
2: {"name": "Leather Armor",  "armor": 2,  "value": 10, "class": "Light"},
....
19: {"name": "Dagger", "damage" : int(random.randrange(1, 4)), "value": 2, "Type": "Dagger"},
20: {"name": "Dagger + 1", "damage" : int(random.randrange(1, 4) + 1), "value": 200, "Type": "Dagger"},
21: {"name": "Dagger + 2", "damage" : int(random.randrange(1, 4) + 2), "value": 750, "Type": "Dagger"},
22: {"name": "Dagger + 3", "damage" : int(random.randrange(1, 4) + 3), "value": 2000, "Type": "Dagger"}
}
```

Every time I attempt to call `"damage"` it just returns the same result. I understand that this is because the random number is generated one and then saved to that dictionary key.

How would I go about generating a random number every time damage is called?

Comment: When you say call damage do you mean there is a function called `damage` or do you mean using your dictionary? e.g. `itemList[1]['damage']`?

Comment: Short answer: I would not put it in a dictionary. Longer answer: of course you can also put a function in a dictionary or override getitem or do some other trick, but in the end, the best answer is: don't.

Comment: How do you call "damage" in a dictionary?

Comment: I mean I use the dictionary. I am not sure how to add items with associated IDs without a dictionary.

Comment: In that case I suggest you instead use a dictionary of class instances as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39563871/355230).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go to the trouble of making the things in `itemsList` instances of a class. Although you might think that's overkill, doing it will give you a lot of programming flexibility later. It'll also make a lot of the code easier to write (and read) because you'll be able to refer to things using dot notation instead of via indexing which means you'll not only be able write to now use `itemsList[19].damage` instead of `itemsList[19]["damage"]`. You'll also use the same syntax for all other attributes such as `itemsList[1].name` and `itemsList[2].value`, as well as be able to write conditional code like this:

```
if hasattr(itemsList[2], 'Class'):
    # do something based on itemsList[2].Class
```

Here's what I mean:

```
import random

class Gear(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['_damage'] = kwargs.pop('damage', False)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    @property
    def damage(self):
        return int(random.randrange(*self._damage)) if self._damage else 0

itemsList = {
    1: Gear(name="Padded Armor", armor=1, value=5, Class="Light"),
    2: Gear(name="Leather Armor", armor=2, value=10, Class="Light"),
    # ...
    19: Gear(name="Dagger", damage=(1, 4), value=2, Type="Dagger"),
    20: Gear(name="Dagger + 1", damage=(1, 5), value=200, Type="Dagger"),
    21: Gear(name="Dagger + 2", damage=(1, 9), value=750, Type="Dagger"),
    22: Gear(name="Dagger + 3", damage=(2, 6), value=2000, Type="Dagger"),
}
```

To answer your follow-on questions in one comment below:

`kwargs` is a dictionary of all the keyword arguments passed to the `__init__()` constructor method. (`__dict__` is the name of a dictionary where each instance stores its attributes.) See [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html?#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another) in the documentation.

`damage` is defined by the class using a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) decorator which is a simple way to actualy make it a "data descriptor". This sets things up so that whenever you reference a class instance's `damage` attribute, it will call a function to retrieve/determine its current "value". See the [*Descriptor HowTo Guide*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=property) for more information on Python descriptors.

Comment: This is a good solution, but what is kwargs and how does damage vary by weapon in your code?

Comment: The only issue I have with it is that the weapons each have different damage ratings, such as range being (1, 5) and (1, 9). In your code, the range is only (1,4), right?

Comment: Yes, I hardcoded it to that, but this is something that could be added.

Comment: See latest update where `damage` now specifies the range (as well as whether there is any). This is what I mean about making it a class gives you a lot of additional flexibility. It also minimizes the ripple-effect from changing things.

Comment: When calling itemsList[21].damage is get error 
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem by adding a `print(itemsList[21].damage)` to the end of the code currently in my answer—so I guessing there must be something else wrong. Make sure you have `_damage` in all the right spots.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123739/discussion-between-dragoonknight-and-martineau).

Answer (score 3):

You would store a function that generates a random number, not the random number itself, in the dictionary. (By the way, if your dictionary's keys are just sequential integers, consider using a list instead.)

```
from random import randrange    
itemsList = [
  {"name": "Padded Armor",  "armor": 1,  "value": 5, "class": "Light"},
  {"name": "Leather Armor",  "armor": 2,  "value": 10, "class": "Light"},
  ....
  {"name": "Dagger", "damage": lambda: randrange(1, 4), "value": 2, "Type": "Dagger"},
  {"name": "Dagger + 1", "damage": lambda: randrange(1, 4) + 1, "value": 200, "Type": "Dagger"},
  {"name": "Dagger + 2", "damage": lambda: randrange(1, 4) + 2, "value": 750, "Type": "Dagger"},
  {"name": "Dagger + 3", "damage": lambda: randrange(1, 4) + 3, "value": 2000, "Type": "Dagger"}
]
```

Then, you simply call the function to get an actual damage roll:

```
# Roll damage for a dagger + 3
damage = itemsList[22]["damage"]()
```

Comment: How would this dictionary look as a list?

Comment: That's what I put in the answer. It's a list of dictionaries, rather than a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Oh that's genius! I see it now. But why do I get ""int" is not callable" when I try to call the function.

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't get any such error from this code.

Comment: I found where I believe the issue lies, but haven't resolved the "int is not callable error. When I print `itemsList[22]["damage]()` it does not give me the error, but when I print `damage = movesfirst.equippedWeapon["damage"]()` I get the error.

Answer (score 3):

You may find it reduces the repetition in your code to store just the damage weighting (still called `damage` in my code) in your dictionary and have a separate function to calculate the actual damage. e.g.

```
from random import randint

itemsList = {
1: {"name": "Padded Armor",  "armor": 1,  "value": 5, "class": "Light"},
2: {"name": "Leather Armor",  "armor": 2,  "value": 10, "class": "Light"},
19: {"name": "Dagger", "damage" : 0, "value": 2, "Type": "Dagger"},
20: {"name": "Dagger + 1", "damage" : 1, "value": 200, "Type": "Dagger"},
21: {"name": "Dagger + 2", "damage" : 2, "value": 750, "Type": "Dagger"},
22: {"name": "Dagger + 3", "damage" : 3, "value": 2000, "Type": "Dagger"}
}

def getdamage(item):
    return randint(1, 4) + item['damage']

# test code
for i in range(20):

    item = randint(19, 21)
    damage = getdamage(itemsList[item])
    print("I used item %d and made damage %d" % (item, damage))
```

Now your random function is only in one place and if you decide to change it later it will be less work.

One thing I don't get though is why have the armour and weapons in one list? You could pass the index of some armour to the damage function and get an error.

Comment: The only issue I have with that is not all of my weapons are (1, 4) in damage.

Comment: oh ok, maybe then the damage modifier could be expressed as a range?